# How to save Image retrieved from gallery into New folder inside External Sdcard in Android

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I have created a folder in SDcard and also retrieve image from gallery to imageview. I want to save this imageview file image in to my external sdcard folder Multimedia/Images

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent ginetnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(ginetnt,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return encodedImage;
}
```

And this is coding for create Folder SdCard

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    String folder_main = "Multimedia";
    File Mul= new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);

    if(!Mul.exists()) {
        if(!Mul.mkdir()){
            Toast.makeText(this, Mul + " can't be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, Mul+" can be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, Mul+" already exits.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    File Images= new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/" +folder_main, "Images");

    if(!Images.exists()) {
        if(!Images.mkdir()) {
            Images.mkdirs();
        }    
    }

    File Audio= new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/" +folder_main, "Audio");

    if(!Audio.exists()) {
        if(!Audio.mkdir()) {
            Audio.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    File Video= new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/" +folder_main, "Video");

    if(!Video.exists()) {
        if(!Video.mkdir()) {
            Video.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, what is the issue you face?

Comment: i cant directly save image which is retrieve on imageview

Answer (score 0):

First extract the `Bitmap` from your `ImageView`.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Then you can save to your gallery with the below method.

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/YourAlbum";
    File dir = new File(file_path);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();//create a file to write bitmap data

    File f = new File(dir, "yourImageName" + ".png");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
}
```